# Does the series $\frac{1}{2}\ln 2+\frac{1}{4}\ln 3+\frac{1}{8}\ln 4+\frac{1}{16}\ln 5+\cdots$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

It seems to me, by trial and error, that this series converges to $1$. Is this true? How do I prove it either way?

Comment: Do you want the answer to the question in your title, or to the question in your text?

Comment: [No, it does not converge to $1$](https://tio.run/##Hco5DoAgEADAWl6xJXjggp0Jj7FAINGFrDS@Ho@pp9w1ZlpaS2fJXOHcahTsL3CAYs8MBImANwpe2tEgolpF94XB/VkfOUhSs9XY95Imo0ThRFW@R7X2AA)

Comment: According to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28n%3D2%2Cinfty%2Clog%28n%29%2F2%5E%28n-1%29%29), it converges to $-2\operatorname{PolyLog}^{(1,0)} \left(0,\dfrac12 \right)$.

Comment: ^ which is equal to$$1.015667845736876784378083681444152748492436866865201859072$$

Comment: Lower bound: $S > \frac12\ln 2+\ldots +\frac1{64}\ln 7+\ln 8\cdot(\frac1{128}+\frac1{256}+\ldots)=\frac12\ln 2+\ldots +\frac1{64}\ln 7+\frac1{64}\ln 8=1.009\ldots >1$

Comment: Also, truncating the series gives $\frac12\ln 2 + \dots + \frac{1}{256}\ln 9 = 1.006\ldots > 1$.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note 
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\ln(k+1)}{2^k}\leq \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k}{2^k}=3/2
$$
where the final equality is the usual geometric series game. Thus your series converges, since omitting finitely (here 1) many terms has no effect on convergence.

Comment: The lower limit on the sums should say $n=1$, right? Or are you omitting the first term intentionally?

Comment: I omitted the first term for the estimate to hold. I will add a note to this effect

Comment: This gives $\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln (k+1)}{2^k}\right) - \frac12\ln 2 \le \frac32$ so the full sum is less than $\frac32 + \frac12\ln 2\approx  1.8$.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite as

$$\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{\log n}{2^{n-1}}$$

which clearly converges e.g. for ratio comparison with $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is obviously convergent but it does not converge to $1$. By Frullani's integral we have

$$S=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n+1)}{2^n}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-(n+1)x}}{2^n}\cdot\frac{dx}{x}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2(1-e^{-x})}{(2e^x-1)x}\,dx$$
on the other hand
$$ 2S = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n+1)}{2^{n-1}}=\log(2)+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n+2)}{2^n}   $$
$$ S = \log(2)+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$
$$2S=\log(6)+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n+2}\right) $$
$$ S = \log(3)+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}\right)$$
$$\begin{eqnarray*} S &\geq& \log(3)+9\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(8)-\log(9)}{2^n (n+2)^2}\\&=&36\log^2(2)\log(3)-54\log^3(2)+\left(9\pi^2-\frac{243}{4}\right)\log(2)+\left(\frac{83}{2}-6\pi^2\right)\log 3\\ &> & 1.0149.\end{eqnarray*}$$